# Shorten path name with initial letters for prompt

Tags: path, zsh

Can we have `~/a/very/long/path/name` shorten to `~/a/v/l/p/name` for zsh promt?

I saw my vim buffer display the path `~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/plugin/youcompleteme.vim` as `~/.v/p/Y/p/youcompleteme.vim` and wonder if we can do similarly for bash/zsh prompt. This will save some space for a small monitor like laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution using regex:

```
$ echo "~/a/very/long/path/name" | perl -pe 's/(\w)[^\/]+\//\1\//g'
~/a/v/l/p/name

$ export PS1='$(echo $PWD | perl -pe "s/(\w)[^\/]+\//\1\//g") '
```

Comment: You've just saved my life :), save a year for me :D cheers. But if we could use `sed` instead will make it faster?